# Export all functions to switch page to one single class (Xamarin.iOS / C#)

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I try to do a `Xamarin.iOS` app with `C#`.
Now I have on each `UIViewController` a function called `ChangePage()` to switch the current `UIView`:

```
    public void ChangePage()
    {
        UIViewController lobbyViewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("LobbyViewController") as LobbyViewController;
        lobbyViewController.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical;
        PresentViewController(lobbyViewController, true, null);
    }
```

So the question is, if it possible to export all this `ChangePage()` functions to one class? Because when I try I have several errors...

Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you do a Base ViewController Class , put all the Change Page code in there and subclass the base class to use those common methods on your ViewControllers ?

Comment: I think I can't do this or I don't know how... Because my viewControlelers have already a subclass: `UIViewController`

Comment: The BaseViewController should subclass UIViewController. See example below on my answer how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you do a Base ViewController Class , put all the Change Page code in there and subclass the base class to use those common methods on your ViewControllers ?

See example below

```
public class BaseViewController : UIViewController
{
    public void ChangePage()
    {
    UIViewController lobbyViewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("LobbyViewController") as LobbyViewController;
    lobbyViewController.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical;
    PresentViewController(lobbyViewController, true, null);
    }
}
```